# Includesvg with % sign

Tags: characters, svg

I am using `\usepackage{svg}` to include an svg file using `\includesvg{filename.svg}` and compiling using `pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex`

This generally works like a charm. However I encountered a problem when the svg file (created by inkscape) includes the percent character (%).

During compilation pdflatex gives the following error message:

> Runaway argument?
>
> {\color [rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox (0,0)[lt]{\lineheight {1.25}\smash {\begin \ETC.
>
> ! File ended while scanning use of \put.
>                  \par
>   l.29
>    \includesvg{filename.svg}

As a quick and dirty fix I can convert the font in the svg into a path and everything works, but how can I include an svg that contains a proper % character into LaTeX?

---

Sample code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{svg}
\begin{document}
\includesvg{filename.svg}
\end{document}
```

This uses the svg-image at [filename.svg](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cQ2dikt7AhlBGSrV7cly6vJdcCuBX0so), which is a simple svg file with only a %-sign as text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 210 297"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg8"
   inkscape:version="0.92.3 (2405546, 2018-03-11)"
   sodipodi:docname="filename.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.35"
     inkscape:cx="400"
     inkscape:cy="560"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1022"
     inkscape:window-height="746"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="20"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-style:italic;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:6.61458302px;line-height:125%;font-family:Sans;-inkscape-font-specification:'Sans Italic';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       x="43.089287"
       y="111.79166"
       id="text10"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan8"
         x="43.089287"
         y="111.79166"
         style="stroke-width:0.26458332px">%</tspan></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sample code added.

Comment: `inkscape` rejects the SVG file as invalid

Comment: @egreg My inkscape (ver 0.92.3) does not complain. In fact I created the file with inkscape, so it would be strange if it rejected the SVG. Can you see the file in the browser or in some other viewer?

Comment: Firefox doesn't balk, but inkscape 0.92.2 does. But the graphic interface of `inkscape` opens it. Weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error appears to be in inkscapes combined tex/pdf export as it fails to quote the `%` in text. It is also hard to use `\catcode` to make `%` a normal chanacter that does not need quoting as it inserts a `%` at the end of almost every line.

the simplest fix it to edit `svg-inkscape/filename_svg-tex.pdf_tex` (which is generated after the first run)

```
\put(-0.11824539,0.01843611){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}\textit{%}\end{tabular}}}}%
```

changing `%` to `\%` to get

```
   \put(-0.11824539,0.01843611){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}\textit{\%}\end{tabular}}}}%
```

the package does not over-write the file on later runs so it will be included without error if you re-run latex on the main file.

Answer (score 1):

By design, the `svg` package renders text in the SVG file as latex. There are two straightforward solutions:

1. If you want text in the SVG rendered as latex, use proper latex syntax (i.e. escape the `%` with a `\`).
2. If you don't want text in the SVG rendered with latex, provide the option `inkscapelatex=false` when you load the `svg` package or when you invoke the `includesvg` command.

If you want to split the difference — e.g. you want text to render with the document font, but you don't want `%` to be interpreted as a comment — then David Carlisle's answer has you covered.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me a lot when I encountered a lot of error messages for a simple figure even though other figures that I implemented the same way hadn't given any problems compiling.

@David Carlisle's fix definitely works, however, it was more obvious (and maybe even easier) for me to just change the "%" in the picture itself (meaning in the Inkscape-Window, editing the file) to an "\%", as you would in any .tex file.

Just leaving this here in case this might help someone.