# includesvg newly generates pfd_tex files every time it is executed

Tags: pdftex, svg, inkscape

I'm using the `svg` package and `includesvg` to include svgs in my document. As I need so escape `%` signs in my pictures, I need to edit the `.pfd_tex` files in the `svg-inkscape` directory (as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461317/includesvg-with-sign)). This usually worked out as desired but now all files in the `svg-inkscape` directory are newly generated every time I compile my document and with that, the escaped characters are overwritten every time.
Does someone have an idea of how I could fix that and only generate the `.pfd_tex` and `.pdf` files for newly included svgs?

Comment: if the text is inside `\put` then you could try not editing the files and instead put `\let\oldput\put\def\put{\bgroup\catcode\`\%=12 \xput}\def\xput(#1)#2{\oldput(#1){#2}\egroup\ignorespaces}`  untested :-)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. For me, `svg` dutifully warns me that I have modified the `.pdf_tex` file and that it will not be overwritten. Can you provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/48973)? Do you have a current version of both LaTeX and `svg`?